# Difference between "import something" and "from . import something" in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

Directory Structure:

```
| Packages
    | noobpy
        | __init__.py
        | linalg.py
    | main.py
```

linalg.py:

```
def inv():
    print("inv called")
```

main.py :

```
import noobpy as np
np.linalg.inv()
```

In __init__.py:

when I use:

```
import linalg
```

It throws in the error that "**No module named 'linalg'**", when running main.py

but when I use:

```
from . import linalg
```

inside of _*init_* ,it works just fine, **even though I can call linalg.inv inside of _*init_* in both the cases.**

Comment: which file do you run ? main.py ?

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary , yes.

Comment: @Pranav I get different error : `No module named 'linalg'`. Are you run it with Pycharm ? because I think Pycharm will automatically add the workspace to the environment variable

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary , yes , I have corrected it in the question as well, I dont know why the first time it showed the error differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Posting as a comment before closing as a duplicate.)

When you run `main.py`, there are certain directories added to the Python search path where the import mechanism will look for module. The directory `main.py` itself is in is added to the path. In this case, it *only* contains the package `noobpy`. The directory `noobpy` itself, you must note, is *not* on the search path.

When you try to use the absolute `import linalg`, no directory on the search path contains a module named `linalg`, so the import fails.

When you try to use the relative import `from . import lining`, the `.` refers to the current package, which is `noobpy` itself, and `noobpy` *does* contain the module `linalg`.